# Prime number question involving GCD.

Tags: number-theory

Prove: where $a$ is an integer and $p$ is prime

If $\gcd(a, p^2) = p$ then $\gcd(a^2, p^2) = p^2.$

I have used Bezout's identity and said:

$av + p^2u = p$

$av = p - p^2 u$

$av = p(1 - pu)$

Then squaring both sides:

$a^2v^2 = p^2(1 - pu)^2$

I'd like to say this equation has some significance. So here I am stuck.

I'm open to alternative methods on proving this (please) or some detail to where I am flawed (please). The solution in the back of the textbook makes no sense to me as it's *very* brief.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just because one is talking about the $\gcd$ one _does not have to_ use Bézout coefficients. Even though for many it s a Pavlov response, there are often simpler arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $gcd(a,p^2)=p$ then $p\mid a$, so $a=pq$ and $a^2=p^2q^2$

Now $gcd(a^2,p^2)\le p^2$, and the conclusion follows.

Comment: ...Now $gcd(a^2,p^2)≤p^2$? The answer by Casteels point out  gcd(m,n)≤min(m,n), clears the less than or equal part up. How do i deduce that it is EQUAL to $p^2?$

Comment: @HMPARTICLE If $p,q$ are positive and $p\mid q$ then $p\le q$. You have that $p^2\mid a^2$ and $p^2\mid p^2$ so the gcd $\ge p^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

$\gcd(a,p^2) =p \implies p^2 \mid a^2 \implies \gcd(a^2,p^2) =p^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly $\gcd(a^2,p^2)\geq p^2$ since $p^2$ divides $p^2$ and, since $p$ divides $a$, $p^2$ divides $a^2$.

But $\gcd(m,n)\leq \min(m,n)$ for any $m,n$ and so $\gcd(a^2,p^2)\leq \min(a^2,p^2)\leq p^2$.

Both $\gcd(a^2,p^2)\geq p^2$ and $\gcd(a^2,p^2)\leq p^2$ can only happen if $\gcd(a^2,p^2) = p^2$.

Answer (score 0):

As $p|a$ , so let us write $\dfrac ap=k$ , then $av+p^2u=p \implies kv+pu=1 \implies k^2v^2+(2kvpu+p^2u^2)=1 \implies$

$k^2v^2+w=1 \implies k^2p^2v^2+wp^2=a^2v^2+wp^2=p^2$ , where $w$ is an integer ; as

g.c.d.$(a^2,p^2)|a^2v^2+wp^2$ , so gc.d.$(a^2,p^2)|p^2$ ; also $p^2|a^2 \implies p^2|g.c.d.(a^2,p^2)$ , hence

$g.c.d.(a^2,p^2)=p^2$